# Python IndexError being thrown even though it's inside two except blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling, runtimeexception

This is probably a really silly error, but alas I am relatively new to Python and I find this error perplexing so any help would be appreciated. It's probably a relatively simple error, but searches on the site have so far not solved the issue. Here is the method that is giving me all of these problems:

```
def loggable(func):
    def log(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            import traceback
            import sys
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            exception_string = traceback.format_exception(type(ex), ex, tb)
            [self.error_log.appendText(item) for item in exception_string]

            m = qg.QMessageBox()
            m.setIcon(m.Warning)
            m.setText(ex.args[0])
            try:
                m.setInformativeText(str(ex.args[1]))
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                m.setDetailedText(str(ex.args[2]))
            except IndexError:
                pass
            m.exec_()
            raise

    return log
```

The exception from this line

```
m.setDetailedText(str(ex.args[2]))
```

is being thrown even though it's inside of not one but TWO catch blocks. I am trying to figure out what the issue could be and any help would be appreciated.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skylion/Git/popupcad/popupcad/guis/editor.py", line 335, in <lambda>
    popupcad.manufacturing.joint_operation2.JointOperation2)}})
  File "/home/skylion/Git/popupcad/popupcad/guis/editor.py", line 51, in log
    m.setDetailedText(str(ex.args[2]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Where is the traceback?

Comment: @user3100115 just added it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line of the outer exception handler is `raise` which will reraise the last exception, which is apparently attempting to call `m.setDetailedText`.  That fails, but its exception is now the most recent, and gets re-raised when you hit `raise` at the end.

To raise the original exception, change it from `raise` to `raise ex`

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, your last statement `raise` will re-raise the previous exception.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions